# how do i convert xml file to file type in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, file, web-inf

i am trying to use rest to show that i can create a File from an .xml document.
this is my code below. whenever i run it, it will return "not working", implying that the file does not exist. 
the articles.xml file is sitting in my WEB-INF folder, i just can't figure out how to make this work.
is this the wrong layout for the filepath?
am i able to convert the xml to a file like this?

```
@Path("test")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test()
{
    try 
            {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } 
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
            {
        return "caught";
    }

        File file = new File("/WEB-INF/Articles.xml");
        if (file.exists()) 
            return "its working"; 
        else
            return "not working";


}
```

Comment: the initial "/" means an absolute path, remove it to use the path relative to the working directory. Moreover, you can return the absolute file path to inspect what's happening using `file.getCanonicalPath()` to see the complete file path

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to load WAR resources is via the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). This can be injected using the [Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation.

```
  @Context
  private ServletContext context;
  private Document articles;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    try {
      InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/Articles.xml");
      try {
        articles = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                         .newDocumentBuilder()
                                         .parse(in);
      } finally {
        in.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) { /*TODO: better handling*/
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }

  @Path("test")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String test() {
    return articles == null ? "not working" : "its working";
  }
```

*Tested on Glassfish 3.1.1.*